# Selecting mySQL index that meets multiple condtions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Index  |  Condition
1      |     A
1      |     B
1      |     C
2      |     A
2      |     B
3      |     A
```

In mySQL, how would I select the index number that meets condition A and condition B. As in I want it to only select 1 and 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select Index 
From yourable 
WHERE
    Condition IN ('A','B')
Group by
    Index 
Having count(DISTINCT Condition) = 2
```

Yep as prdp said group by and count.  I prefer this pattern over conditional aggregation but both should get you the answer you want.